# How to map a Column to Identity Column from a Source to a Table in Azure SQL using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory and Azure SQL.

I am using using `Copy data` Activity from `Move and transform`.

My source is a csv file with same column names as the column names in my destination table in Azure SQL.

Now, I have an **auto-increment primary key** `My_Emp_ID` in my table(sink).

`ADF` is asking to match this column with source, but I do not have any such thing in my source(csv).

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Please let me know how can I successfully load the data and the auto-increment key automatically increment value in Azure SQL.

Comment: I don't/haven't used ADF< but cant you just remove that column (using the trash can icon); if the column is an `IDENTITY` then you shouldn't be passing a value to it as trying to do so will case an error.

Comment: Why not *remove* that mapping? On the far right of the screenshot is a Delete icon

Comment: delete your id column and process the pipeline.

Comment: Awesome guys.. thank you all.. this thing was bugging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue while copying data from a CSV file to an SQL table, which has an auto-increment primary key as shown below:

[image]

Following @Thom A's suggestion, I deleted that column as shown below:

[image]

And tried to copy the data using the copy activity. The copy activity ran successfully, as shown below:

[image]

The data was successfully copied, as demonstrated below:

[image]